# TypeError: System Admin.contains not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete the related records on click of a button which is working fine.Now i want the delete logic to work only the profiles which contains 'xyz' in their name.
I am getting an error 'TypeError: System Admin.contains not a function'.

Any other methods which i can use here.

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}
    alert('{!$Profile.Name}') 
    try{ 
        if('{!$Profile.Name}'.contains('xyz')){
```

Comment: Try replacing `if('{!$Profile.Name}'.contains('pss')){` with `if(String.valueOf({!$Profile.Name}).contains('pss')){` or ``if((String){!$Profile.Name}.contains('pss')){``. Maybe the profile name needs to be typecasted as a String, although I'd expect it to be retrieved as a String so this is just a guess.

Comment: I am currently trying includes() and i guess that will work. Will try your idea too Dan.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't do this, because it can cause you problems later. Instead, simply use [Custom Permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/custom_perms_overview.htm). Create a new custom permission, and you can check for it like this:

```
if({!$Permission.canDeletePss}) {
    // rest of code here
```

This allows you to specify the permission per profile or even as part of a permission set that can be assigned *per user*, at will, without having to modify your code.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.I didn't find any solid documentation to implement this as i am not aware of this.could you please guide me how i can implement this?Some good documents links would be awesome.

Comment: @Samir There's a link in the answer. To summarize, you (a) create a new custom permission in Setup, (b) edit any profiles and/or permission sets that should have this permission, and then (c) write the code as I've demonstrated above.